# Wrap lines of text within image boundaries using gd

Tags: php, image, gd, truetype

I am trying to write text from a db to images. The text some times contains lengthy lines so that it does't fit in one line on image.

As of now I am getting the output as: http://prntscr.com/29l582

This is the code for this:

```
$imageCreator = imagecreatefrompng($i+1 . ".png");
        $textColor = imagecolorallocate($imageCreator, 0, 0, 0);
        $textfromdb = $factformatted['fact'];
        $y = imagesy($imageCreator) - 228;
        $dimensions = imagettfbbox(20, 0, $fontname, $textfromdb);
        $x = ceil(($imageWidth - $dimensions[4]) / 2);
        imagettftext($imageCreator, 20, 0, $x, $y, $textColor, $fontname, $textfromdb);
        imagepng($imageCreator, "./fact".$i.".png");
```

Can someone help me to make it work?

Comment: How do you actually want to fit this? Insert line breaks? Change font size etc?

Comment: I prefer line breaks, but if the string is actually bigger than the image width, then reducing the font size will have to be done!

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599988/3679900) discussion for possible approach of wrapping words by **max permissible text-width in pixels** by exploiting [`imagettfbbox()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) function

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [wordwrap](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function and the [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) function to truncate the text in multiple arrays of string, then print them:

```
$word = explode("\n", wordwrap ( "A funny string that I want to wrap", 10));
```

You obtain this output:

```
 array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "A funny"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "string"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "that I"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "want to"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "wrap"
}
```

Than you can elaborate it (cutting the text, print each string on different lines, etc...).

Example (printing on new lines):

```
...
$dimensions = imagettfbbox(20, 0, $fontname, $textfromdb);
$y = imagesy($imageCreator) - 228;
$text = explode("\n", wordwrap($textfromdb, 20)); // <-- you can change this number
$delta_y = 0;
foreach($text as $line) {
    $delta_y =  $delta_y + $dimensions[3];
    imagettftext($imageCreator, 20, 0, 0, $y + $delta_y, $textColor, $fontname, $line);
}
...
```

To center both vertical and horizontal:

```
...
$dimensions = imagettfbbox(20, 0, $fontname, $textfromdb);
$margin = 10;
$text = explode("\n", wordwrap($textfromdb, 20)); // <-- you can change this number
$delta_y = 0;
//Centering y
$y = (imagesy($imageCreator) - (($dimensions[1] - $dimensions[7]) + $margin)*count($text)) / 2;

foreach($text as $line) {
    $dimensions = imagettfbbox(20, 0, $fontname, $line);
    $delta_y =  $delta_y + ($dimensions[1] - $dimensions[7]) + $margin;
    //centering x:
    $x = imagesx($imageCreator) / 2 - ($dimensions[4] - $dimensions[6]) / 2;

    imagettftext($imageCreator, 20, 0, $x, $y + $delta_y, $textColor, $fontname, $line);
}
...
```

Comment: This now comes like this: http://prntscr.com/2btaek I will try to fix it by myself, but since I am new to this any help would be appreciated. I am trying to center it both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: I changed the answer to center the text, take a look. I can't test, but it should work...

Comment: I did this and its aligning the y part: http://pastie.org/private/ryutguudjnk7sjp5afsbdw. But your $x part gives me blank image. I think the text is going towrds the outer part of image! :( When I checked the value of x x:-841.5

Comment: This worked for me! http://pastie.org/private/fg6d1ky4spfzaufivxvwjw Anyway thanks for your help mate. I will accept yours as accepted annswer!