# PHP - GD - how wrap a text

Tags: php, gd

I created an image 500X200 with white background and text on it.
How can I wrap "Text" if it will be long in GD.

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); 
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagefill ( $image, 0, 0, $white );

...

imagettftext($image, 18, 0, $x, 100, $black, $font, "text");
```

Comment: You could probably use the `imagettfbbox()` function to determine how big the text would be and compare the results to the width of the image. The `imagettfbbox()` returns an array of points so you would need to do some calculations based upon left & right of the bounding box. The string `$text` could then be split and the newline character inserted

Comment: Agreed with **@Professor Abronsius**, [`imagettfbbox()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) function can be used to wrap words by **max permissible text-width in pixels**. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599988/3679900) discussion for possible approach

Answer (score 3):

[GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) supports rotation, vertical and horizontal alignments, configurable line heights and leading, word wrap (obviously), character wrap, and text outlines. While this frankly belongs in a class (or a namespace) due its size, it’s in a function. You’re free to trim away unneeded functionality.

**Example usage:**

```
$size = 14;
$angle = 34;
$left = 10;
$top = 40;
$color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
$fontfile = "arial.ttf";
$text = "Test";
$opt = array('width' => 300,'line_height' => 15,'orientation' =>array(ORIENTATION_TOP, ORIENTATION_LEFT),
'align' => ALIGN_LEFT,
'v_align' => VALIGN_TOP,
'outlines' = array(
array(5, imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 255, 0)),
array(2, imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255)),
),
// More options 
);
imagettftextboxopt($im, $size, $angle, $left, $top, $color, $fontfile, $text, $opt);
```

**UPDATE:**

And also refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453505/wrap-lines-of-text-within-image-boundaries-using-gd)