# Wrap Text in imagettftext()

Tags: php, word-wrap, imagettftext

i got this script to generate an image out of a random jpg in a directory, adding a random slogan from a database:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

include '../connect.php';
require_once 'random.php';

$timestamp = time();
$date = date("d.m.Y_G", $timestamp);


$slogan = $mysqli->query("SELECT `text` FROM `slogans` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

    $slogan_txt = $slogan->fetch_assoc();



    $bg = get_rand_img('../../images/');
    $imgPath = '../../images/' .$bg;

$text = $slogan_txt[text];
$image = $imgPath; 
$font = "font.TTF";
$font_size = "25";

$image_2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image_2,0,0,0);

$image_width = imagesx($image_2);  
$image_height = imagesy($image_2);

$text_box = imagettfbbox($font_size,$angle,$font,$text);
$text_width = $text_box[2]-$text_box[0]; // lower right corner - lower left corner
$text_height = $text_box[3]-$text_box[1];

$x = ($image_width/2) - ($text_width/2);
$y = ($image_height/2) - ($text_height/2);

imagettftext($image_2,$font_size,0,$x,$y,$black,$font,$text );

header ("Content-type: image/png");
imagejpeg($image_2);



?>
```

works fine so far.

Now there are some slogans with to much words for one row. i need them to be wrapped and also be centered!

can't use wordwrap in imagettftext(), so i need to explode it somehow.

i found some functions on the web, but they dont work as expected. maybe i just dont know how to combine them with my existing code!

maybe someone got a workign example from own projects?

thanks so far!

Comment: Well, it worked now. Found something interesting here and thats it! Just needed to add the calculation for where to start with the text (responding to imagesize). [GDtext by stil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27742547/3433549 "gdtext by stil") Thanks!

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18476314/3679900) discussion for possible approach of wrapping words by **max permissible text-width in pixels** by exploiting [`imagettfbbox()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageftbbox.php) function

Answer (score 0):

This explodes a string and puts it text into a second string if the first is longer then 14, i guess you could build up on this.

```
$string = "";
$string2 = "";
$name = explode(" ", $name);
foreach ($name as $n) {
    if (strlen($string) + strlen($n) > 14) {
            $string2 .= $n . " ";
        } else {
            $string .= $n . " ";
        }    
}
```

for centering the text you would need to do something like:
(imagesisex/2) - digits * pixelsize